# Unable to log continously to my local file ! Help,Anyone?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('https') > -1) {
        var tabURL = tab.url;
        console.log("\n<TimeStamp>" + getTimestamp() + "</TimeStamp><Browser>Chrome</Browser><URL>" + tabURL + "</URL>\n");
        window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024, initFs);

        function initFs(fs) {
            fs.root.getFile
            ('log.txt', { create: true, exclusive: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.isFile = true;
                fileEntry.name = 'log.txt';
                fileEntry.fullPath = '/log.txt';
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
                    bb.append("\n<TimeStamp>" + getTimestamp() + "</TimeStamp><Browser>Chrome</Browser><URL>" + tabURL + "</URL>\n");
                    fileWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Question: Whenever I surf website using HTTPS,I want to log every website that I visit into my local file. I have an issue here,for example,If I surf "HTTPS://google.com" first & other HTTPS websites later,I can only log the "HTTPS://google.com" in my log file but not other HTTPS websites continously. Could someone guide me along & identify out the bug inside the code ? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do all HTTPS websites get logged?

Comment: @ the console.log(),all HTTPS website can be logged,but @ the local file,only the first HTTPS website that I visited was logged & the rest was not logged. Thats the problem... :)

Comment: Any of the filesystem calls might be reporting errors, I would suggest that you add error handlers to display any error codes produced.

Comment: Yes I added the errorhandler & now it tells me there is an "invalid modification error" & it fails to log continously to the local file ? How can I correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can avoid the error by removing "exclusive: true" in the call to getFile

Comment: Thanks a million. You have been a great help.

Comment: From the FAq: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)